# mkdir and joinpath doesn't works in Google

Tags: google-colaboratory, mkdir

```
 save_dir = Path('/OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy')
 save_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

 img_dir = save_dir.joinpath('images')
 img_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

 %cd ~/OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy/
 %cd ~/OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/images/
```

*No such file or directory: '/root/OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy/'
/root/OpenPose_Pose_transfer
No such file or directory: '/root/OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/images/'
/root/OpenPose_Pose_transfer*

mkdir and joinpath do not work with Google Colab

Answer (score 0):

From [pathlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

> If parents is true, any missing parents of this path are created as
>   needed; they are created with the default permissions without taking
>   mode into account (mimicking the POSIX `mkdir -p` command).

Since in your case the parents probably do not exist yet, specify the `parents=True` parameter to `mkdir()`. Also, the last line should be `%cd /OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy/images/` since `images` is a sub-directory of `roy`.

Also, since you are creating `OpenPose_Pose_transfer` directory at `/`, do not precede the path with `~` ( which expands to `/root` in Colab)

Changed code:

```py
 from pathlib import Path
 save_dir = Path('/OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy')
 save_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

 img_dir = save_dir.joinpath('images')
 img_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

 %cd /OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy/
 %cd /OpenPose_Pose_transfer/data/source/roy/images/
```